# How to achieve sub-directory sites in wordpress multisite?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, multisite

I have a wordpress setup with Network admin enabled.
And I have following different sites configured.

```
http://example.com/ipl ,
http://example.com/cricket,
http://example.com/football,
http://example.com/ileague,
http://example.com/sports
```

But what I want to configure is the following without redirecting (URL should not change in the address bar)

> http://example.com/sports/cricket should serve content from 
>       http://example.com/cricket 
>   http://example.com/sports/cricket/ipl should serve content from http://example.com/ipl 
>   http://example.com/sports/football should serve content from http://example.com/football
>   http://example.com/sports/football/ileague should serve content from http://example.com/ileague

Answer (score 0):

Please add following code in .htacess file.

```
RewriteRule ^sports/cricket/ipl?$ /ipl [NC]
RewriteRule ^sports/cricket?$ /cricket [NC]
RewriteRule ^sports/football/ileague?$ /football [NC]
RewriteRule ^sports/football?$ /football [NC]
```